# Xcode 6 - I Can't connect anything from my IB to ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't control-drag anything from my screen to ViewController.swift. This is making me very mad and I don't know how to fix it. I have been looking on the internet for hours and can't seem to make it work.
[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/F8cJcTX.png

Comment: It is very annoying. Try one thing. Write property manually in .swift file and than try to connect.

Comment: Your UIViewController in Interface Builder needs to have it's "Custom Class" attribute set to the name of your UIViewController subclass - which in your case is named ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it wont connect you must set the File's Owner in the XIB file. Select File's Owner in the Placeholders panel. Move over to the Utilities panel and make sure the Custom class, in  Identity Inspector, is set to what ever your viewcontroller is named.
[image]

I Hope this will help you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

May be the class of your xib will not be  the viewcontroller to which you are controll dragging.

Or,It can be because your zoom out level is high..Zoom in to say 50 or 100% and see if you can control drag.